# HQL subquery issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get the latest record from a table. My sql is as follow.

> Select * from (select * from TABLE_1 WHERE paid=1 order by PAYMENTDATE
>   DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1

I tried to do it with HQL with the mapping pojo classes. It gave errors. My HQL is as follow.

> SELECT pay FROM (SELECT payment FROM  com.Table1 as payment WHERE
>   payment.paid=1 ORDER BY payment.paymentDate DESC) as pay where
>   pay.ROWNUM = 1

The error is,

> net.sf.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: SELECT [SELECT pay FROM
>   (SELECT payment FROM com.TABLE1 as payment WHERE payment.paid=1 ORDER
>   BY payment.paymentDate DESC) as pay.ROWNUM = 1 ]

Normal queries without subqueries are working.

Eg:

> SELECT payment FROM  com.Table1 as payment WHERE payment.paid=1

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Why you need do to multiselect BTW?

Comment: Usually i will go with `Query query = session.createQuery("select p from pay where p.paid =1 order by p.paid  DESC");`

Comment: Ya. I'm trying to do this with HQL as we didn't use native queries for the project yet

Comment: HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses, HQL doesn't support sub-queries in the FROM clause [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Comment: Oh. I tried to find examples also. Couldn't find other than with select and where.

Comment: @isurujay use `join` for your requirement.

Comment: sure #soorapadam. I'll try

Comment: I will use the HQL for following query "select * from TABLE_1 WHERE paid=1 AND PAYMENTDATE = (select max(PAYMENTDATE) from TABLE_1 WHERE paid=1)"